# How do I customize the gantt chart in odoo9 project management?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

How do I customize the gantt chart in odoo9 project management?

Please give me a reference about gantt chart

Answer (score 0):

currently web_gantt module not available for Odoo 9 Community version.
just look this link. -->
[Link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/gantt-view-odoo-9-community-version-srikesh-infotech)

Comment: Please let me know how do I customize the existing project module in odoo9..i.e I want to add the gantt chart to my project module..